# Convert Java long type value of specific format to seconds/milliseconds

Tags: java

How to convert long value of specific format to seconds or milliseconds in an efficient way.

Example long value we have in our system is **20210425** which represent the date of format **yyyyMMdd**.

```
long val = 20210425;
```

I need to convert above to seconds or milliseconds, the desired output I'm looking here would be: 1619308800000

Comment: please share the desired format here as well

Comment: "I need to convert above to seconds or milliseconds" but you say the value represents a local date, that is, a 24h (ish) long period in an unspecified time zone. To convert to seconds/millis, you need to specify the zone and the time within that day (e.g. the start of the day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Do not use math for date-time handling. We have the *java.time* classes for that.

```java
LocalDate                             // Represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.
.parse(                               // Interpret a piece of text as representing a date value.
    String.valueOf( 20210425L ) ,     // Becomes a `String` object, "20210425".
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE  // YYYYMMDD format. 
)                                     // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC )       // Determine the first moment of the day in that time zone or offset.
.toInstant()                          // Adjust from some offset to an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.
.toEpochMilli()                       // Calculate a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 UTC.
```

> 1619308800000

## Details

Read all of the valid points in the [correct Answer by Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67261372/642706). Then consider this code solution.

Convert your `long` variable to text, and parse as a date. More preferable would be skipping the `long` altogether if possible, for reasons discussed in that other Answer.

The textual version of your number `20210425` happens to be representing a date using the “basic” (compact) version of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for dates. The `DateTimeFormatter` class has a constant with that format predefined, [`DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```java
long val = 20210425;
String input = String.valueOf( val ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Apparently you want a count of milliseconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC. And apparently you want to interpret that input as being seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

So apply an offset of zero to the date while getting the first moment of the day, to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. From that extract a `Instant`, the basic building block of *java.time*, always in UTC by definition.

```java
Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ).toInstant() ;
```

Get a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```java
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Tz5X6t).

> localDate.toString(): 2021-04-25
>
> instant.toString(): 2021-04-25T00:00:00Z
>
> millisecondsSinceEpoch: 1619308800000

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: This is the best solution. `LocalDateTime` would be a meaningless detour. You may use `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` if preferred.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for reminding me about `BASIC_ISO_DATE`. I improved the Answer with that.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you shouldn't be using a `long` to represent a date like that.  A date is not an integer.  (Just like phone numbers and credit cards are not integers.)

However, if you already have a dates represented as a `long` values ... like that ... then there are a couple of ways to approach this.

### Using a date/time parser

First you need to do is to convert the `long` to a `String`; e.g. using `Long.toString(long)`.

Then you use a date parser to convert the string a date/time object

Finally you get the millisecond time from the date/time object

### Using arithmetic

First do some arithmetic to extract the year, month and day numbers from your `long`.

Next do some more arithmetic to convert the year / month / day to a number of days since Jan 1st 1970.  This is non-trivial because you need to account for leap years AND the fact that different months have different numbers of days.

Finally multiply by the number of milliseconds in a day.

### Using `LocalDateTime` to do the arithmetic

There is another way too.  Use arithmetic to extract the year, month and day as above.

Then use `LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0)` to create a `LocalDateTime`.  (Make sure that `month` and `day` are based correctly!)

Finally get the millisecond time from the `LocalDateTime` object

---

A final note.  As Andy Turner points out in a comment, you haven't specified what timezone the `long` is based on or the timezone of the millisecond clock that you are targeting.  These will need to be taken into account ... no matter what method you use to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts.

1. Convert `long` to a date.
2. Get milliseconds for that date.

For the first part, simply do some basic arithmetic to extract the required values.

For the second part, if you are using at least Java 8, then use the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

```java
/*
 * import java.time.LocalDateTime;
 * import java.time.ZoneOffset;
 */
long l = 20210425;
int year = (int) (l / 10_000);
System.out.println("year = " + year);
int month = (int) (l % 10_000 / 100);
System.out.println("month = " + month);
int day = (int) (l % 100);
System.out.println("day = " + day);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, 0, 0);
System.out.println(ldt.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("Z")));
```

Note that I could not ascertain, from your question, whether you need to consider the time zone, hence I used an offset of 0 (zero). You would need to change the `ZoneOffset` if relevant.